# Lua 5.1 custom loader for a shared object library

Tags: c, lua

How, if at all possible, is it to make a custom function to replace the third searcher in the `package.loaders table`. From reading the manual [*require/package.loaders*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require), the manual is unclear how to dynamically link the application with the library.

> Once it finds a C library, this searcher first uses a dynamic link facility to link the application with the library...

```
test
├── example.lua
└── libcexample.so
```

libcexample.so

```lua
require 'libcexample'
```

What is this `dynamic link facility` and is it possible to use outside of the normal package loaders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very OS-specific question, and it is not Lua's place to document how to utilize the APIs provided by your system(s) (or how to implement a dynamic linker entirely).

[*5.1/loadlib.c*](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loadlib.c.html) contains the specifics for Lua's implementation(s):

The default implementation of `package.loaders[3]` is [`loader_C`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loadlib.c.html#loader_C), which calls [`ll_loadfunc`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loadlib.c.html#ll_loadfunc), which in turn calls an OS-specific version of `ll_load` and `ll_sym` looking for the appropriate entry point (and `ll_unloadlib`).

- On Linux/Solaris/BSD/etc., this uses [`<dlfcn.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dlfcn.h.html)'s `dlopen` and `dlsym` (and `dlclose`).
- On Darwin (Mac OS X), this uses [`<dyld.h>`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-433.5/include/mach-o/dyld.h.auto.html)'s `NSCreateObjectFileImageFromFile` and `NSLookupSymbolInModule` (and `NSUnLinkModule`).

  - Note that modern Darwin (Mac OS X >= 10.3, macOS) deprecates `dyld` in favour of `dlfcn`, so this can be configured to use the latter.
- On Windows, this uses `<windows.h>` ([`<libloaderapi.h>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/))'s  `LoadLibraryA` and `GetProcAddress` (and `FreeLibrary`).

Note: `package.loadlib` is [`ll_loadlib`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loadlib.c.html#ll_loadlib), which also calls [`ll_loadfunc`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/loadlib.c.html#ll_loadfunc), but wrapped with different semantics than `require` / `package.loaders[3]` per the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loadlib).

Of course you can implement all of this yourself, but it requires specific knowledge of your system(s).

Answer (score 1):

> What is this dynamic link facility?

"Dynamic link facility" is the [package.loadlib function](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loadlib).

> is it possible to use outside of the normal package loaders?

Yes

Comment: When trying to load a shared object I use require, updating the package.loaders to use my custom c function, then using lua_load in the c api. How can you load the shared object chunk and ensure it reads it a binary data, and links it to the same libname?

Comment: What is a `shared object chunk`?

Comment: I think I was making an incorrect assumption that Lua code and a shared object can be loaded in the form of chunks. From the reference manual.
> The unit of execution of Lua is called a chunk. A chunk is simply a sequence of statements, which are executed sequentially.